# Passenger + Dreamhost + Django Error

Tags: django, passenger

**Web application could not be started**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dh/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 320, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/dh/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 61, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "passenger_wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
    if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 312, in execl
    execv(file, args)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Directories:
username/root/env
username/root/appname
username/root/public
username/root/static
username/root/tmp
username/root/passenger_wsgi.py
username/root/passenger_wsgi.pyc

**Passenger_Wsgi.py**
    import sys, os
    INTERP = "/home/larson07/local/bin/python"
    #INTERP is present twice so that the new python interpreter knows the actual       executable path
    if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/poll')  #You must add your project here

sys.path.insert(0,cwd+'/env/bin')
sys.path.insert(0,cwd+'/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0,cwd+'/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "poll.settings"
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Thank you in advance!
-E

Answer (score 1):

Your INTERP is likely pointing to the wrong place. To fix this, type `which python` into your terminal, and use the resulting filepath as the INTERP. This worked for me!